# probability normalization in python

Tags: probability

Given the following "un-normalized" set of probabilities (i.e., that do not necessarily sum to 1):

0.22 0.54 0.58 0.36 0.3

What is the normalized set of probabilities? (Enter your answer as a sequence of space-separated numbers.)

Comment: This stinks of homework...

Answer (score 0):

`0.11 0.27 0.29 0.18 0.15`

Normalization factor would be `1 / (0.22 + 0.54 + 0.58 + 0.36 + 0.3) = 0.5`.

And the the normalized value for every probability is `normalization factor * value`.